# Hide and show whole screen upon a button click in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

using Constraint Layout in Android Studio 2.3

Trying to achieve: Show a button on screen start and hide all the other elements in the layout. On that button click , reveal all the other elements but hide the button itself.

Achieved : Using nesting of layouts, if i put button in one layout set it to visible in start, and put all the elements in another layout. i can do the above problem.

Problem : I want to achieve this without nesting of layouts otherwise what's the use of constraint layout. Anyone?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button startButton,playButton;
TextView timerTextView;
TextView resultTextView;
Button button0,button1,button2,button3;
TextView sumTextView;
TextView pointsTextView;
ArrayList<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int locationOfCorrectAnswer;
int score=0;
int numberOfQuestions=0;
ConstraintLayout mainLayout;

public void playAgain(View view)
{
    score = 0;
    numberOfQuestions = 0;

    timerTextView.setText("30s");
    pointsTextView.setText("0/0");
    resultTextView.setText("");
    playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    generateQuestion();

    new CountDownTimer(30100,1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000) + "s");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            timerTextView.setText("0s");
            playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resultTextView.setText("Your score is " + Integer.toString(score)+ " / " + Integer.toString(numberOfQuestions));

        }
    }.start();

}

public void generateQuestion()
{
    Random rand= new Random();

    int a = rand.nextInt(21);
    int b = rand.nextInt(21);

    sumTextView.setText(Integer.toString(a)+ " + " + Integer.toString(b));
    locationOfCorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(4);
    answers.clear();

    int incorrectAnswer;

    for(int i=0; i <4 ; i++)
    {
        if(i==locationOfCorrectAnswer)
        {
            answers.add(a + b);
        }
        else
        {
            incorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(41);

            while ( incorrectAnswer == a + b)
            {
                incorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(41);
            }
            answers.add(incorrectAnswer);
        }
    }
    button0.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(0)));
    button1.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(1)));
    button2.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(2)));
    button3.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(3)));
}

public void chooseAnswer(View view)
{
    if(view.getTag().toString().equals(Integer.toString(locationOfCorrectAnswer)))
    {
        score++;
        resultTextView.setText("Correct!");

    }
    else
    {
        resultTextView.setText("Wrong!");
    }
    numberOfQuestions++;
    pointsTextView.setText(Integer.toString(score)+"/"+ Integer.toString(numberOfQuestions));
    generateQuestion();
}

public void start(View view)
{
    startButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    playAgain(findViewById(R.id.playButton));

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    sumTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sumTextView);
    button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
    pointsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pointsTextView);
    timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
    playButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    mainLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);


}
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code? We can maybe simplify it. Also, you dont need to put the button in a seperate layout. Under the constraint layout, have the button and another layout for rest UI components.. Furthermore, you can completely remove layouts and set each UI component as invisible or gone on button click..

Comment: Yes, i didn't but button is separate but all the other in another layout and then View.VISIBLE upon the button click, if i do for individual components is it better than doing using separate layout? because my teacher has told me nesting of layouts is not good practice.

Comment: Number of layouts doesn't have a very big performance hit. It is the level of hierarchy that matters. If you have 7-8 level nesting heirarchy, only then it matters... Unless you post your code, I cannot tell if it is in the most simplified form

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility of an element onClick of the button. An example of this would be something like:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //hide button
    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //show some layout
    textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show some textview
    ....

}
});
```

If you want to retain its space of the button in the layout, use `View.INVISIBLE`. If the button should not occupy any space in the layout after it's invisible, use `View.GONE`.